# What real EIP-1559 base fee on polygon chain?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, web3py

When I call the `fee_history` method from the [web3 library](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.py), the `polygon` node returns a non-null [EIP-1559](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1559) base fee. However, on https://polygonscan.com/gastracker we see a base fee equal to 0. Same on https://polygonscan.com/blocks.

Request on `eth_feeHistory`:

```py
{'jsonrpc': '2.0', 'id': 0, 'result': {'baseFeePerGas': ['0x73', '0x6c', '0x64', '0x5e', '0x5b'], 'gasUsedRatio': [0.2267586, 0.2028314, 0.2325742, 0.3555376], 'oldestBlock': '0x17cc92e', 'reward': [['0x9502f8f8d', '0x9502f8f8d', '0x2ea19dccfc'], ['0x89d5f3011', '0x9502f9000', '0xba43b7394'], ['0x9502f9000', '0xba43b739c', '0x19d81d959c'], ['0x89d5f2ed7', '0x8d8f9fb82', '0xcce4165a2']]}}
```

We see that the base fee is equal to `[115, 108, 100, 94, 91]`. It's on [infura](https://infura.io).
But local node returns 22 Wei as the base fee for the next block.

What is the real base fee on polygon chain, zero or not? If not zero, why the base fee is so small, like 90 Wei? And why does a local node always return 22 Wei as the base fee?

### UPDATE:

Ok, now I see that the base fee will appear on the Polygonscan. But the question remains why a local node can return 22 Wei?